# Content cacheing with PHP and CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching, curl, lamp

I have a couple of things I'm working on, namely a page that issues five or six cURL requests and processing content on them.

I'm working with CodeIgniter on a LAMP stack but am open to other options. Naturally I would prefer to **not** rewrite the application.

I would like to know if there are any ready-made / easily learned caching methods. Primarily I'd like to check if the page has changed since I last scrapped it. If it has, redownload and present. If it hasn't, serve up a cached copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a go with my [Cache library](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/code/codeigniter-cache).

Combine that with my [cURL library](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/code/codeigniter-curl) and you'd have some very simple syntax.

```
// un-cached
$this->load->library('curl');
echo $this->curl->simple_get('http://example.com/');

// cached
$this->load->library('cache');
echo $this->cache->library('curl', 'simple_get', array('http://example.com/'), 120);
```

That'll cache your page request for two minutes.